# Error when uploading to Slack from R

Tags: r, ssl, curl, slack-api, slack

I have been using the slackr function to upload messages and graphs from R to Slack. However, for the past few weeks, I receive the following error when trying to use slackr:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"

I have looked everywhere, re-issued the API token for Slack but cannot find a solution for this error.

Comment: The problem sounds unrelated to Slack and rather related to the cURL installation. Have you checked that it can access other HTTPS URIs without issue? I’ve had repeated issues with cURL being unable to find its local certificate store.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph for the suggestion. I was also not able to access Google sheets and found a solution for both by reinstalling the "openssl" package on R.